# How to compare all elements between Datatable and Array's months?

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I'd like to ask you guys for a question that helps from you.

I have a DataTable with months and amounts, as shown below, and an array named after all the months of the year. How could I build a structure that would return the months of the year with the quantities described in the DataTable along with the other months with the quantity in zeros?

Before

```
Mes Qt
Dec 6
Jan 2
Nov 2
```

After

```
Mes Qt
Jan 2
Fev 0
Mar 0
Abr 0
Mai 0
Jun 0
Jul 0
Ago 0
Set 0
Out 0
Nov 2
Dec 6
```

My code:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Data");
dt.Columns.Add("Quantidade");
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Dec", 6 });
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Jan", 1 });
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Nov", 4 });

var monthsRange = Enumerable.Range(1, 12)
                .Select(e => e > 0 ? Convert.ToDateTime("20/" + e + "/2000").ToString("MMM", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US")) : "")
                .ToArray();
```

Comment: Use `new DateTime(2000,e,20)` instead of `Convert.ToDateTime` to avoid cultural issues. BTW, what format do you want to have the answer in?

Comment: Your sample data has the `Quantidade` column as `string` - did you mean for it to be `int`?

Comment: @NetMage, I already used new `DateTime(2000,e,20)`, but I have got a problem with database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want the answer as `List<anonymous>` then I would convert the `DataTable` to a `Dictionary` and then use `monthsRange` to create the final `List`:

```
var monthsRange = Enumerable.Range(1, 12)
                .Select(e => new DateTime(2000,e,20).ToString("MMM", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US")))
                .ToList();

var dtd = dt.AsEnumerable().ToDictionary(r => r.Field<string>("Data"), r => r.Field<string>("Quantidade"));

var ans = monthsRange.Select(Mes => new {
            Mes,
            Qt = dtd.TryGetValue(Mes, out var qt)
                    ? qt
                    : "0"
        })
        .ToList();
```

Comment: Can you me explain how do you got achive this result?

Comment: @EduardoLopes I am not sure I can explain - combining sparse data with a full set of values is a common need, and there are a few common ways to do it using LINQ.

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like that (I wasn't sure what type of data is intended for output):

```
        DataTable initialData = new DataTable();
        initialData.Columns.Add("Mes");
        initialData.Columns.Add("Qt");
        initialData.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Dec", 6 });
        initialData.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Jan", 1 });
        initialData.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Nov", 4 });

        DataTable outputData = new DataTable();
        outputData.Columns.Add("Mes");
        outputData.Columns.Add("Qt");
        foreach (var month in Enumerable.Range(1, 12))
        {
            var monthName = new DateTime(2000, month, 1).ToString("MMM", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"));
            int.TryParse(initialData.Select($"Mes='{monthName}'").FirstOrDefault()?["Qt"].ToString(), out int count);
            outputData.Rows.Add(new object[] { monthName, count });
        }
```

Comment: I'cant show count.

Comment: You cannot show 'count' of what?